# Server Side pagination and filtering in Angular dropdown

Tags: angular, pagination, filtering, dropdown

I am working with a large data set. I have to populate the dropdown with millions of records. Hence I need pagination and filtering on the server-side, similar to the data table. We are using PrimeNG with Angular 8. However, PrimeNG does not provide any sort of serverside pagination.

Any dropdown with server-side pagination will work if they provide a solution in the Angular way.

Please suggest.

Comment: why not using autocomplete?

Comment: Well, the user wants to see records based on the sorted alphabet. (top 10 with serverside pagination buttons) At the same time autocomplete search in the dropdown. Do you think this user interface is not intuitive?

Comment: a dropdown with a huge number of element is not a good choice, if i want an element at the page  number 10 ... i have to navigate to it by clicking 10 times means, 10 calls to your server ...

Comment: but with search and autocomplete, it will only one call, which is a search call by string to get element that match the query string

Comment: What server technology are you using? ASP.NET Core, Codeigniter, Symphony? For my own project I've built a [Select2 component](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/tree/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/src/app/controls/select2). Maybe you can build something similar.

Comment: These are external APIs that can provide paginations. I am thinking to implement infinite scrolls and loads the dropdown when user is scrolling and reaching at the bottom of the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started searching based on my requirement. Actually we have millions of datasets that we need to bind in the dropdown. Based on all the dropdown available in the Angular. I [like the `ng-slelect` most](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select). The `ng-slelect` provide infinite scrolling hook which did my work. It's called virtual scroll. My second choice is anything among Angular material and PrimeNG autocomplete. Though these two controls do not provide virtual scrolling. I found [this article very useful](https://medium.com/coding-in-depth/angular-binding-dropdown-with-huge-data-set-af2ef245e548).

Thanks everyone for comment and help.